# Stop browser from decoding encoded strings when downloading JS object as JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, object, browser

I am trying to store a snippet of JS code as JSON, by first storing the snippet in a JS object and then downloading that object as a JSON file. I can encode the JS fine using `encodeURI`

For example:

```
encodeURI("var a = 100")
```

...which gives a nice encoded string:

```
"var%20a%20=%20100"
```

...which can be stored in a JS object like this:

```
data = {
         "code" : "var%20a%20=%20100"
       }
```

But if I download this object as JSON:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = 'my_file.json';
link.href = "data:json," + JSON.stringify(data);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

... the downloaded file shows a decoded snippet when the file is opened, which makes the JSON invalid.

I am using Chrome as the browser. Do browsers automatically decode encoded strings when downloading JS objects as JSON files?

Comment: `data:json,{\"code\":\"var%20a%20=%20100\"}` Maybe try encoding `JSON.stringify(data)` as well? Then when it is decoded by the browser the "code" is still encoded.

Comment: I tried that as well, still happens. It seems like the semicolon in the saved snippet might be causing the problem.

Comment: Tried replacing all instances of the asterisk with ****** but it still has the problem. There are line breaks in the saved JSON file causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to use both `encodeURIComponent` and `encodeURI` in order for the encoding to be preserved in downloaded JSON file.

```
encodeURIComponent(encodeURI( // the code snippet
```

Comment: Why was this the case? May you share a quick example of how it worked out?

Comment: Not sure what else there is to add. The details provided in the question outline the problem quite specifically. My answer brings a solution to that specific problem.